# New In XAMMP and php: Got this error while installing

Tags: php, codeigniter, xampp

```
[ErrorException]

Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function CodeIgniter\CLI\mb_strpos() in G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\CLI\CLI.php:719
Stack trace:
#0 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\CLI\CLI.php(161): CodeIgniter\CLI\CLI::parseCommandLine()
#1 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\CLI\CLI.php(959): CodeIgniter\CLI\CLI::init()
#2 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\Autoloader\Autoloader.php(264): include_once('G:\\Aj Apps\\Ci4\\...')
#3 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\Autoloader\Autoloader.php(241): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->includeFile('G:\\Aj Apps\\Ci4\\...')
#4 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\Autoloader\Autoloader.php(219): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadInNamespace('CodeIgniter\\CLI...')
#5 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\app\Views\errors\cli\error_exception.php(6): CodeIgniter\Autoloader\Autoloader->loadClass('CodeIgniter\\CLI...')
#6 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\app\Views\errors\cli\production.php(5): include('G:\\Aj Apps\\Ci4\\...')
#7 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\Debug\Exceptions.php(235): include('G:\\Aj Apps\\Ci4\\...')
#8 G:\Aj Apps\Ci4\Ci4_project\system\Debug\Exceptions.php(132): CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->render(Object(CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException), 500)
#9 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Debug\Exceptions->exceptionHandler(Object(CodeIgniter\Exceptions\FrameworkException))
#10 {main}
  thrown

at SYSTEMPATH\CLI\CLI.php:719
```

Comment: Please add any relevant information regarding the framework/version and state any questions regarding this stacktrace.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you don't have **mbstring** extension enabled on your PHP server.
I believe you are working with CodeIgniter framework. Which PHP version are you using? Please make sure you have latest version of PHP installed.

Comment: Im using PHP 8.0 (8.0.10) : 
VS16 x64 Thread Safe (2021-Aug-25 09:24:54)   XAMPP Version: 8.0.10 : Codeigniter 4.1.4